# Setting the environment for XML transformation in an Azure App Service Deploy task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I'm using an Azure DevOps Pipeline to release an ASP.NET MVC system to an Azure Web App.

I've configured the build *not* to apply the XML transforms, so I can apply them later, during the release step, and the same build artefact can be released to multiple environments.

The build works fine, and I end up with an artefact containing an untransformed web.config, and the environment-specific transform files.

The Azure App Service Deploy task has a check-box called XML Transformation, which displays the following help text:

> The config transforms will be run for *.Release.config and
>   *.<EnvironmentName>.config on the *.config file. Config transforms will be run prior to the Variable Substitution. XML transformations
>   are supported only for Windows platform.

At the moment I'm trying to set up a release into a test environment, but the `Web.Release.config` is being applied, rather than the `Web.Test.config`. I've searched everywhere I can find for a place to define the environment to make the release use the test config, but I can't find anywhere.

There's a [similar question](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4776) on GitHub which shows the following screenshot:

[image: Environment Option]

Unfortunately mine doesn't look like that:

[image]

Am I trying to do the right thing? If so, where do I set the environment?

Comment: Not sure about any case-sensitive like `test and Test`issue causing this?

Comment: "Deploy EMS to Test" is a just name of of your CD pipeline. Likewise "CloudProd" is the name for CD pipeline for GitHub question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your stage name is just 'Test' and not 'Deploy EMS to Test', [reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=vsts#xml-transformation).